# Delete Row if populated with blanks and zeros within a range

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I have a report where i need to remove the rows with no data in the cells or a zero within a range column C to O.

This code i have almost does it perfectly, but i found a fatal flaw in the logic. If the row has a positive and negative value that sum to zero it will be deleted while i would still need to retain that row.

I really appreciate the assistance from this site as I have been able to really automate many of my reports and help people in other departments! you guys rock! Thank You!

```
Dim rw As Long, i As Long
rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = rw To 6 Step -1
If Application.Sum(Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 17)) = 0 Then
Rows(i).Delete
End If
Next
```

Comment: How about `if .Min(..) = 0 & .Max(...) = 0` then all must be 0

Comment: Is there a function i can use for it to search for only blanks and zeros in the cell of the row, and if so to delete the row within the specific columns of C to O?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking the SUM, loop through each cell and check if its valid.

To explain this better I will use pseudo code for you:

1. Create a flag variable and set it to false
2. Create a loop that will check each cell in a row
3. If a valid number if found, set the flag to true
4. Before moving to the next cell, check if your flag is still false
5. If your flag is false -> Continue to next cell
6. Loop through to the end of all of the cells in the row

Pseudo-Code made into rough code

```
Dim rw As Long, i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim validRow As Boolean
validRow = false

rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = rw To 6 Step -1
    Set rng = (Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 17))
    For Each cell In rng
         If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.value <> 0 Then
               validRow = true
            End If
         End If
         If validRow = true Then
        Exit For
         End If
    Next cell
    If validRow = false Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
    validRow = false
Next
```

[@LL edit: changed >0 to <>0 too look for anything different than zero, to account for rows populated with only negative values]

Comment: I just looked up flag variable, im still a big noob in the VBA world. This is above my current understanding, though i understand what you wrote, sort of, when you broke it down. I actually stole part of this code from researching a similar question when i searched google and then modified it to fit my report row and column range. any further assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A flag variable would just be true/false :) Sorry. Let me see if I can write this up for you or at least get you closer

Comment: Updated the answer @LLF I used notepad to code this so if there are any errors I apologize. It should be pretty good. Take backups before you run the code

Comment: its only taking away rows with blanks but not the ones populated with zero's.

Comment: Add a check in there for a zero next to IsEmpty (Similar to how you did it before)

Comment: im trying to comment in the zero "0", even did some searches on google for isempty and zeros but couldn't find a way to remark it.  Im sorry for added help, im just not understanding how to add it, tried (,0 "0", or, =) I just dont know enough yet, just have the ability to edit other peoples code, but slowly im learning what they mean when used. i really do appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @LLF added 0 check. Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

First, I guess, there's error in `Resize` - it should be 13 - not 17.
Second, if you have lots of data to remove, you can use `AutoFilter`.

#### First way.

Altering your code:

```
Sub FFF()
    Dim rw As Long, i As Long, cntZeroes%, cntEmpty%
    rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = rw To 6 Step -1
        With Cells(i, 3).Resize(, 13)
            cntZeroes = Application.CountIf(.Cells, 0)
            cntEmpty = Application.CountIf(.Cells, vbNullString)
            If cntZeroes = 13 Or cntEmpty = 13 Then Rows(i).Delete
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

#### Second way.

Using helper column `P` (as it's next to `O`) with `AutoFilter`. It's rather complex, but it's faster than row-by-row deleting:

```
Sub FFF2()
    Dim rw As Long, i As Long, cntZeroes%, cntEmpty%
    rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = rw To 6 Step -1
        With Cells(i, 3).Resize(, 13)
            cntZeroes = Application.CountIf(.Cells, 0)
            cntEmpty = Application.CountIf(.Cells, vbNullString)
            If cntZeroes = 13 Or cntEmpty = 13 Then
                Cells(i, "P") = 1
            End If
        End With
    Next
    With Rows(5)
        .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=1
        On Error Resume Next
        With .Parent.AutoFilter.Range
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

## Empty Cells Treated As Zeros!?

When developing code for the deletion of rows and/or columns it is good practice to use the Hidden property instead of the Delete method, so the wrong things don't get deleted. Therefore I would conclude that it is good practice to post it in that way, too.
You will have to change `cBlnDEL` to `True` to enable the **DELETE** feature, which I would recommend you do only after you have checked the code with the **HIDDEN** feature active.

### A 'Fast' Union Version

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Deletes or hides empty rows, and rows containing zero (0) in     *
'             a specified range, in the ActiveSheet (of the ActiveWorkbook).   *
'*******************************************************************************
Sub DeleteBlankAndZeroRows()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  Const Col1 As Integer = 3         ' First Column of Source Range
  Const Col2 As Integer = 13        ' Last Column of Source Range
  Const Row1 As Integer = 6         ' First Row of Source Range
  Const cBlnDEL As Boolean = False  ' If True, Delete. If False, Hide.

  Dim rng As Range                  ' Check Range
  Dim rngU As Range                 ' Target Union Range

  Dim Row2 As Long                  ' Last Row of Source Range
  Dim i As Long                     ' Source Range Rows Counter
  Dim j As Long                     ' Source Range Columns Counter
  Dim k As Long                     ' Deleted Rows Counter
  Dim strMsg As String              ' Msgbox Text

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet ' A reminder of where this is happening.
    ' Calculate last row of Source Range.
    Row2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Set bogus reference to "aquire range level" (Parent).
    Set rng = .Cells(1, 1)
  End With

  ' Loop through each row in Source Range.
  For i = Row1 To Row2

    ' Calculate the Check Range for current row in Source Range.
    Set rng = rng.Parent.Cells(i, Col1).Resize(1, Col2)

    ' If the cell at the intersection of column Col1 and the current row
    ' is 0, add it to the Target Union Range.
    ' Note: Unexpectedly, the value of an empty cell is treated as 0 here.

    ' Loop through each cell of the (one-row) Check Range.
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

      If rng.Cells(1, j).Value = 0 Then ' If 0 is found.
        k = k + 1                         ' Count to be deleted rows.
        If Not rngU Is Nothing Then       ' There already is a range in rngU.
          Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng.Cells(1, 1)) ' Add another.
         Else                             ' There is no range in rngU.
          Set rngU = rng.Cells(1, 1)              ' Add one.
        End If
        Exit For
'         Else                            ' If 0 is NOT found.
      End If

    Next ' (Cell in (one-row) Check Range)

  Next   ' (Row in Source Range)

  ' Note: If no 0 was found, the Target Union Range does NOT contain a range.

  If Not rngU Is Nothing Then ' Target Union Range contains range(s).
    If cBlnDEL Then ' DELETE is active. Delete Target Union Range.
      strMsg = "DeleteBlankAndZeroRows successfully deleted " & k _
          & " rows in " & rngU.Areas.Count & " areas."
      rngU.Rows.EntireRow.Delete
     Else           ' HIDDEN is active. Hide Target Union Range.
      strMsg = "DeleteBlankAndZeroRows has successfully hidden " & k _
          & " rows in " & rngU.Areas.Count & " areas."
      rngU.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
   Else                       ' Target Union Range does NOT contain range(s).
    strMsg = "You may have used the DELETE feature of " _
        & "DeleteBlankAndZeroRows recently, because " _
        & " it could not find any zeros. Nothing deleted."
  End If

ProcedureExit:

  Set rngU = Nothing
  Set rng = Nothing

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  MsgBox strMsg

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  strMsg = "An unexpected error occurred. Error: " & Err.Number & vbCr _
      & Err.Description
  GoTo ProcedureExit

End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```

**The previous code hides or deletes each row where there is a red cell in the yellow area as shown in the image.**

[image]

### Special Versions (Not Recommended)

```
Sub DelBlankAndZeroRowsDontKnowHowIGotOutOfMyBedThisAfternoonVersion()
  Dim rw As Long, i As Long, j As Long
  Dim rng As Range, rngU As Range
    rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = rw To 6 Step -1
      Set rng = Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 13)
      For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        If rng.Cells(1, j).Value = 0 Then
          If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
            Set rngU = Union(rng.Cells(1, 1), rngU)
           Else
            Set rngU = rng.Cells(1, j)
          End If
        End If
      Next
    Next
    rngU.Rows.Hidden = True
  Set rngU = Nothing
  Set rng = Nothing
End Sub

Sub DelBlankAndZeroRowsThinkImGonnaStayInBedTodayVersion()
Dim rw As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim rng As Range, rngU As Range
rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = rw To 6 Step -1
Set rng = Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 13)
For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
If rng.Cells(1, j).Value = 0 Then
If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
Set rngU = Union(rng.Cells(1, 1), rngU)
Else
Set rngU = rng.Cells(1, j)
End If
End If
Next
Next
rngU.Rows.Hidden = True
Set rngU = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
End Sub

Sub DelBlankAndZeroRowsNeverGonnaGetUpVersion()
Dim rw As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rng As Range, rngU As Range
rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row: For i = rw To 6 Step -1
Set rng = Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 13): For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
If rng.Cells(1, j).Value = 0 Then
If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
Set rngU = Union(rng.Cells(1, 1), rngU)
Else: Set rngU = rng.Cells(1, j): End If: End If: Next: Next
rngU.Rows.Hidden = True: Set rngU = Nothing: Set rng = Nothing: End Sub
```

Comment: I even know that you're answering by first line HUGE FONT! 

Comment: I'm uploading a better version. Take a look.